# Correct object instantiation / persistence ordering and annotations

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

> My use case is simple. There are two entities: `Server` and `Client`. **Each Server can have Multiple Clients**. This should be pretty simple really...

### What I need

I require the following as a result of this:

- Calling `$server->getClients()` will return all `Client` entities associated with that server
- Calling `$client->getServer()` will return the `Server` entity associated with that client

I believe that, according to the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html), this is a **One-To-Many Bidirectional** relationship.

> A one-to-many association has to be bidirectional, unless you are using an additional join-table. This is necessary, because of the foreign key in a one-to-many association being defined on the “many” side. Doctrine needs a many-to-one association that defines the mapping of this foreign key.

The docs above give a really simple [example](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) of `Product` and `Feature` entities, which I have attempted to adopt for my `Server` to `Client` use case.

### The Problem

Firstly, I can't seem to get the annotations right to create a `Client` entity, assign it to a newly created `Server` entity, then persist / save them. The `Client` entity always has `null` for the `server_id` attribute. What is the ordering required? Why are my annotations not working?

Secondly, I can't figure out if I need a join table to be able to do `$client->getServer()` or the other way around: `$server->getClients()`. **Do I need a join table to fulfil the above criteria?** I tried to add a join table anyway, but no join table was actually created when running `doctrine orm:schema-tool:update`.

### The Code

*Note: I do have Setters / Getters on both ends for `Client` and `Server`*

```php
/**
 * Class Server
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="servers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Model\Repository\ServerRepository")
 */
class Server
{
   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    private $id;

   /**
    * @var ArrayCollection
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Model\Entity\Client", mappedBy="server", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    */
    private $clients;
}

/**
 * Class Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="clients")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Model\Repository\ClientRepository")
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

   /**
    * @var Server
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Model\Entity\Server", inversedBy="client")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="server_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $server;
}
```

I have tried multiple combinations of creating `Client` and `Server` entities, calling `$server->addClient(new Client));` etc, persisting both in different orders and more.

What **exactly** am I doing wrong? Why do I have `null`? What do I need to fix my annotations and object persistence in order to achieve the methods `::getClients()` and `::getServer()` being made available to me?

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the other question, which part of my answer solved your problem? :)

Comment: @DanFromGermany Not only were my setters / getters incorrect (I couldn't see this requirement in the docs), but the `ManyToOne` was the wrong way around. Your answer was very useful and will probably be useful to future users as well. Also, the `id` change was required. Thanks!

Comment: I was not sure about the `server_id` / `id` thing. Glad it helped you! Doctrine is not that easy to get into but it's worth learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the mutators (getter and setter) methods are present (afaik, at least in my doctrine version) the getter setter are not generated by doctrine, you need to implement them. And the array collection must be in the contstructor:

in `Server` Entity:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addClient(Client $client) {
    $this->clients->add($client);
    return $this;
}

public function removeClient(Client $client) {
    if ($this->clients->contains($client)) {
        $this->clients->remove($client);
    }
    return $this;
}

public function getClients() {
    return $this->clients;
}
```

Your entity is looking good (annotations), not sure wether you really need `repositoryClass="App\Model\Repository\ClientRepository"`.

The order of things is not important as long as you have the entity persisted once.
An entity is automatically persisted when fetched by `findBy` or when added to an already persisted entity. Example:

```
$server = $entityManager->getRepository('App\Model\Entity\Server')
                        ->findOneByName('test');

$server->addClient(new Client());

// client and server are now both persisted

$entityManager->flush();

// stuff is now saved in the database
```

**Update:**

Sorry I didn't read that you already have getters and setters.

When updating the schema, try the following:

```
./doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata
./doctrine orm:schema-tool:update
./doctrine orm:generate-proxies
```

**Update:**

**Found your error:**

```
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="server_id", referencedColumnName="id")
```

`server_id` is not present. `Server::id` is, but not `Server::server_id` **:-)**

Correct:

```
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
```